# Why does DBMS_SESSION.session_trace_enable create multiple files?

Tags: oracle, trace

I have a trace on a session configured like this:

```
execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET TRACEFILE_IDENTIFIER = ''TEST1''';

DBMS_SESSION.session_trace_enable (waits => TRUE,
                                   binds => TRUE,
                                   plan_stat      => 'all_executions'
                                      );
-- do SQL stuff --
DBMS_SESSION.session_trace_disable();
```

When completed executing, I have some 80 .trc files created.  Why is that, and is there a way to force all tracing to one file?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be for at least 2 possible reasons:

1. Shared server architecture: SQL trace files belong to server processes, but when you use shared server architecture, your session does not have a single dedicated server process, your session can exist in several different server processes over time.
2. Parallel processing: when your statements run in parallel, each slave thread is a different process and as SQL trace files belong to processes, you have multiple processes running the same statement, hence the multiple trace files.

You can not force the creation of a single trace file, but you can consolidate these traces into a single file with `trcsess`, based on your SID, module name, action name, service or client identifier.